# Add children using REST API in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hey I have a dataset uploaded in the following form:

```
SomeKey

 -> Alphabet

       -a: "['apple', 'ant']"
       -b: "['ball', 'bat']"
```

Now using Rest API, I want to add new children to the object 'Alphabet'. Now if I use POST it inserts a new random key as a child to Alphabet and PUT at https://gamma.firebase.com/SomeKey overwrites the current data completely. How to insert a new child using the REST API?

Comment: Since i wasnt clear the first time: What if i want to make a bulk entry - Add c, d, e and so on, in one call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can address the children directly by URL.

If you wrote "a" and "b" originally to:
/SomeKey/Alphabet

And then wanted to add "c" later, you can just send a PUT request to:
/SomeKey/Alphabet/c

Additional details about the REST API are here:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html